# ASP .NET Publishing Failure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, jscrollpane, publish

I can't publish my web app since I have added JscrollPane.

It keeps hanging atpublishing directory  Scripts/typings/jscrollpane

[image] 
Even if I kill the process

[image]

It still remains there And i have to reboot

If on publish to a folder and then moove the folder to the server everything works....but it's more hassle.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had limited access on the server for some reason our rights where lost/revoked during server reset we weren't able to write on the server anymore. It hanged at random files not only jscrollpane.